# Split text in R dataframe based on string

Tags: r

I want to have a list of .txt documents in a R dataframe, where one column 'doc_title' contains the names of the files, and another column 'text' contains the text in those files.

I have made a dataframe from a directory of .txt files using the following code:

```
> file.list <- list.files(path = ".", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)
> all.files <- sapply(file.list, FUN = function(x)readChar(x, file.info(x)$size))
> df <- data.frame( files= all.files, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This gives me a dataframe with one column and 929 rows. Every row contains the .txt file name, and the contents of the file. So next, I wanted to make a new column based on separating the existing column by '.txt' values. I used the following code:

```
tidyr::separate(df, all.files, sprintf("X%d", 1:4), ".txt")
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
✖ Subscript `var` has size 929 but must be size 1.
```

What can I do?

Comment: you are looking for `str_sub()` of the `stringr` library `data_new<-stringr::str_sub(data, 1L, 4L)`

Comment: I never used `tidyr::separate`, but the documentation `?tidyr::separate` says, that the second argument `col` must be a column name or position. In your case, the name of the filenames in df is `files`, not `all.files`.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Every row contains the .txt file name, and the contents of the file". Assuming a row looks like this

```
testName <- "someFile.txt and here goes its contents"
```

you can first grab the first part with `someFile.txt` using

```
testFileNameWithoutContent <- gsub("(^.*\\.txt).*","\\1",testName) #gives "someFile.txt"
```

Now to get only the file name, you can use another `gsub` which deletes the `.txt` at the end:

```
gsub("\\.txt$","",testFileNameWithoutContent) #gives "someFile"
```

The `gsub` function is vectorized, so you can apply the procedure to the whole column, eg:

```
testNames <- paste0("someFile",1:10,".txt with its content")
gsub("\\.txt$","",gsub("(^.*\\.txt).*","\\1",testNames))
```

Update according to your comment:

```
testNames <- paste0("someFile",1:10,".txt with its content ",rnorm(10))
df <- data.frame(filename=gsub("(^.*\\.txt).*","\\1",testNames), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$content <- mapply(FUN = function(name,nameWithContent) {gsub(paste0("^",name),"",nameWithContent)},df$filename,testNames)
```

Comment: The problem is that using your approach, I only get a list of all the contents of the files. What I am looking for, using your example, is, given that my files look like "somefile.txt and this are its contents" , "anotherfile.txt and some other content", would be presented in a dataframe with as a first column "somefile.txt" "anotherfile.txt" , and as second column "and this are its contents", "and some other content" .

Comment: I updated my answer. Is this now your desired dataframe?